# MySQL truncating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, blob, truncate

I've got a form where people may post book reviews. They give the title of the book, the name of the author and the review text. When the user clicks the button to save the review a javascript function is called:

```
function gravarResenha(id) {
    var livro = $("#resenhatit").val();
    var autor = $("#resenhaaut").val();
    var resen = $("#resenhatex").val();
    if ((livro != "") && (autor != "") && (resen != "")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "resenha/gravar/id/" + id + "/livro/" + livro + "/autor/" + autor + "/texto/" + resen,
            success: function(res) {
                if( res == 1 ) {
                    carregaPagina( 'secliteratura' , 'col02' );
                } else {
                    alert( "Problemas no cadastramento da resenha. Tente novamente." );
                }
            },
            error: function(res) {
                alert( "Problemas no cadastramento da resenha. Tente novamente." );
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert( "Impossível postar uma resenha vazia." );
    }
}
```

The variable resen receives the value of the textarea whose id is #resenhatex. This value is being truncated.

At first I thought it was the fact I was using a TEXT field in my MySQL table. Then I changed it to a LONGBLOB field, considering the reviews may be a bit long.

I also added this type: "POST" in my jQuery AJAX call, because I reminded that GET method has some limitations when it comes to the size of data sent.

Even doing all these changes I still get the same truncated value when I send bigger reviews.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `max-length` on textarea or editor config? Could always check it's length before you send, when you receive and after insert to see where it might be getting cut off

Comment: There is no editor, just a common textarea. Do you know if there is a default max-length for this kind of html object? I haven't set a max-length for this textarea.

Comment: You may have specified method POST now, but you are still putting your data into the URL, so it still gets transferred via GET … use POST _properly_ and specify the data to send as an object.

Comment: Really didn't know this, @CBroe. Going to try it now!

Comment: Go do that. (But this is most likely rather not a problem of GET vs POST, but rather of you neglecting to _escape_ the data properly that you are putting into an URL context.)

Comment: No, you did _not_ escape the data in your code as shown – not for the context “URL”, that you are putting them into.

Comment: Oh, ok! I know what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56829/discussion-between-ederpsampaio-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was heppening every time I had a question mark (?) inside the text passed.

I did the following to solve the problem:

```
var myresen = $("#resenhatex").val();
myresen = myresen.replace(/\?/g, "%3F");
```

And then it worked fine!